# Ruby gems for user interaction in the shell?

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, console

I wonder if there are Ruby gems for user interaction in the shell similar to the Thor::Actions.

Maybe more extensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

highline gem perhaps?